# What is the alternative to SaveRingtoneTask in Windows Phone 8.1 Universal App

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

In WP8.0 saved ringtone by used SaveRingtoneTask, But in WP8.1 it is not available what is the alternative to save Ringtone.

```
 saveRingtoneChooser = new SaveRingtoneTask(); 
 saveRingtoneChooser.Completed += new EventHandler<TaskEventArgs>(saveRingtoneChooser_Completed);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is none. Ringtone Providers are in the list of [Windows Phone 8 features for which there is no Windows Phone Store equivalent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn642486(v=vs.105).aspx).

The closest you can do is use a FileSavePicker or FolderPicker and let the user pick the Ringtones folder. There is no way to explicitly point the pickers to start in this location.

Comment: But i want to save file in ringtones folder